# MySQL String Comparison with Wildcards

Tags: mysql, wildcard, string-comparison

I wrote a query where a user can input a string and get the data related to that string back from the database.

For example, a user will input Apple even though the full name is Apple Inc.

The code would be laid out as so...

```
and Description like '%Apple%'
```

The problem with this is, it will return Snapple along with Apple.
Aside from removing the first "%" wildcard and making the user type more, how can I limit the results to just Apple?

Comment: Why not, `AND Description = 'Apple'` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not understanding the question. If you don't want it to match letters before the passed string, just remove the first wildcard % as you said yourself.

Comment: The description isn't Apple.  It's Apple Inc so that wouldn't return the sought after data.  And I rather keep the wildcard there in case of user error.  Just looking for other suggestions, thanks boys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
WHERE Description RLIKE '[[:<:]]apple[[:>:]]'
```

`[[:<:]]` matches the beginning of a word, `[[:>:]]` matches the end of a word.

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) for all the regexp operators supported by MySQL

Comment: Unfortunately, that wouldn't return the records due to the full name being "Apple Inc" but I will definitely study up on that documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't that work? The space between `Apple` and `Inc` is a word boundary.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change `LIKE` to `RLIKE`, now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - string comparison with wild cards (especially leading wild cards) doesn't really scale using "like". You might want to look at [full-text searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead. This basically gives you "google-like" text searching capabilities.

To answer your question, in most cases, "Apple" is a better match than "Snapple" for the term "apple". So, you could include the concept of "match quality" in the search - something like:

```
select *, 10 as MatchQuality
from table
where description like 'Apple'
union
select *, 5 as MatchQuality
from table
where description like 'Apple%'
union 
select *, 1 as MatchQuality
from table
where description like '%Apple%'
```